# Cannot getting Correct query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Datatable. and it has a column named `data`.

```
data  
-------
10       
20    
30
```

i need to get a column as

```
data  
-------
10/60   
20/60   
30/60
```

i wrote the query as

```
select data/sum(data) 
  from datatable;
```

Comment: Do you want literally the text `10/60` to appear, or for that to be calculated? (~0.166)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i need calculated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the window function `sum` over the entire table (`over ()`):

```
select  1.0 * data / sum(data) over ()
from    tableName
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1c0a/8/0)

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2005+ you can do this:

```
SELECT CAST(data AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST(SUM(data) OVER() AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM Datatable
```

Comment: @Kaf You are looking at SQL Server 2012 docs. Previous to that, the `ORDER BY` inside `OVER()` for aggregations functions like `SUM` or `COUNT` weren't allowed. The `ORDER BY` is required for windows functions like `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`, where an order is necessary

Comment: Yes you are correct. Sorry, Also I was looking for `RANK()`. Updated my comments above.

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
select a.data / b.total       -- will result the quotient of 10/60
from   datatable a, 
       (select SUM(data) total from datatable) b
```

but if you want it to be concatenated

```
select a.data + '/' + b.total -- will result literal string value of 10/60
from   datatable a, 
       (select SUM(data) total from datatable) b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries above*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1c0a/4)

Comment: Last I checked, mixing strings and numerics resulted in an attempted conversion of the string to numeric, not the other way around.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, i fixed them on the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

This works on SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
declare @t table (data int)
insert into @t (data) values (10),(20),(30)

select (data * 1.0)/ SUM(data) OVER () from @t
```

Comment: This should work on SQL Server 2005+ (though without the table variable and the `VALUES` part)

Comment: @Lamak - I wasn't sure, and didn't have a 2005 instance handy. I know some of the aggregate window functions have changed between 5, 8 and 12. So my statement is true but not all-encompassing :-)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where the 60 value comes from, but I would do something like this:

```
select data + '/' + sum(data) from datatable group by data
```

For concatenation, please check this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862(v=sql.80).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you group by `data`you will get 10/10, 20/20, 30/30

Comment: I think you're wrong. That's why I wanted to know what he's trying to do. That would return the data (either 10, 20, 30) / the sum of each one (30 times 10, 45 times 20, etc). If he wants to count the times a value appears, he should use count instead of sum.

Comment: If you group by data then `SUM(data) = data`therefore your select would produce 10/10, 20/20, 30/30 of you cast them to varchar or it would produce 1 for every row in the datable

Comment: Neither of those queries give the results in the question.